# Get list of XML attribute values in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, parent-child, xml-attribute

I need to get a list of attribute values from child elements in Python.

It's easiest to explain with an example.

Given some XML like this:

```
<elements>
    <parent name="CategoryA">
        <child value="a1"/>
        <child value="a2"/>
        <child value="a3"/>
    </parent>
    <parent name="CategoryB">
        <child value="b1"/>
        <child value="b2"/>
        <child value="b3"/>
    </parent>
</elements>
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```python
>>> getValues("CategoryA")
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> getValues("CategoryB")
['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
```

It looks like a job for XPath but I'm open to all recommendations. I'd also like to hear about your favourite Python XML libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really an old hand at Python, but here's an XPath solution using libxml2.

```
import libxml2

DOC = """<elements>
    <parent name="CategoryA">
        <child value="a1"/>
        <child value="a2"/>
        <child value="a3"/>
    </parent>
    <parent name="CategoryB">
        <child value="b1"/>
        <child value="b2"/>
        <child value="b3"/>
    </parent>
</elements>"""

doc = libxml2.parseDoc(DOC)

def getValues(cat):
    return [attr.content for attr in doc.xpathEval("/elements/parent[@name='%s']/child/@value" % (cat))]

print getValues("CategoryA")
```

With result...

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

Comment: Accepted because this is what I ended up using. It's a simple one-liner and I didn't need to install any extra modules. Check out the other answers too - there's some good stuff there.

Comment: python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libxml2
ImportError: No module named libxml2

Comment: @SR query: You'll probably need libxml2 to use this libxml2 example.

Answer (score 7):

[ElementTree 1.3](http://effbot.org/zone/elementtree-13-intro.htm) (unfortunately not 1.2 which is the one included with Python) [supports XPath](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm) like this:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as xml

def getValues(tree, category):
    parent = tree.find(".//parent[@name='%s']" % category)
    return [child.get('value') for child in parent]
```

Then you can do

```
>>> tree = xml.parse('data.xml')
>>> getValues(tree, 'CategoryA')
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> getValues(tree, 'CategoryB')
['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
```

`lxml.etree` (which also provides the ElementTree interface) will also work in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
>>> def getValues(name):
. . .      return [child['value'] for child in soup.find('parent', attrs={'name': name}).findAll('child')]
```

If you're doing work with HTML/XML I would recommend you take a look at BeautifulSoup. It's similar to the DOM tree but contains more functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Using a standard W3 DOM such as the stdlib's minidom, or pxdom:

```
def getValues(category):
    for parent in document.getElementsByTagName('parent'):
        if parent.getAttribute('name')==category:
            return [
                el.getAttribute('value')
                for el in parent.getElementsByTagName('child')
            ]
    raise ValueError('parent not found')
```

Answer (score 4):

My preferred python xml library is [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml) , which wraps libxml2.
Xpath does seem the way to go here, so I'd write this as something like:

```
from lxml import etree

def getValues(xml, category):
    return [x.attrib['value'] for x in 
            xml.findall('/parent[@name="%s"]/*' % category)]

xml = etree.parse(open('filename.xml'))

>>> print getValues(xml, 'CategoryA')
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> print getValues(xml, 'CategoryB')
['b1', 'b2', 'b3]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.x, fetching a list of attributes is a simple task of using the member `items()`

Using the `ElementTree`, below snippet shows a way to get the list of attributes. 
NOTE that this example doesn't consider namespaces, which if present, will need to be accounted for.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    flName = 'test.xml'
    tree = ET.parse(flName)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for element in root.findall('<child-node-of-root>'):
        attrList = element.items()
        print(len(attrList), " : [", attrList, "]" )
```

**REFERENCE:**

> *Element.items()*
>       Returns the element attributes as a sequence of (name, value) pairs.
>       The attributes are returned in an arbitrary order.

[Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 2):

I must admit I'm a fan of [xmltramp](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/xmltramp/) due to its ease of use.

Accessing the above becomes:

```
  import xmltramp

  values = xmltramp.parse('''...''')

  def getValues( values, category ):
    cat = [ parent for parent in values['parent':] if parent(name) == category ]
    cat_values = [ child(value) for child in parent['child':] for parent in cat ]
    return cat_values

  getValues( values, "CategoryA" )
  getValues( values, "CategoryB" )
```